# Cable Stop For Internal Cable Routing

Tags: road-bike, cable, cable-routing

All of a sudden, I desperately need those, but I'm failing to find it on ebay or anywhere else. Maybe I call them wrong? Do they have a specific title or something?

Thanks for help guys, you're the best!

UPDATE: The frame is made of steel not carbon (as shown on the image below). It's a simple steel frame that has holes for internal cable routing.

[image: Cable stops for inside the frame routing]

Comment: I'm not sure, but my guess is that they are custom to the specific frame. Contact the local bike store where you bought the bike or get in touch with the manufacturer of the frame to see if you can get a replacement.

Comment: thanks for you reply! I've bought an old frame and these little things are missing so I'm not sure there are any original left ((

Comment: It is possible they still use the same ones on the current model. I would bring the frame and a ruler into a dealer selling the brand and do a side by side comparison.

Comment: @mikes so you can't buy on like ebay or some such? It's an old BH frame and I seriously doubt if they have a dealership in the place where I live at the moment.

Comment: As @ Kibbee stated I also believe they a brand specific. They appear slightly different from mine. In reality there are not that many carbon frame builders in the world. My guess is that there are not many variations.

Comment: @mikes sorry guys! the frame is made of steal not carbon. I've made the picture just to show the piece I'm looking for. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2):

As all the comments have stated most appear to be brand/ model specific. Since it is an older frame it is possible that it didn't have them. Some older frames snaked the entire cable housing thru the frame. The stop was on the component, (brake, derailleur or frame mounted cable stop). If you search for custom bike frames builders you may find some local sources. If you don't have your heart set on internal cables, you can use bolt on frame mounted stops. You will need to measure the frame tube diameter and figure out if you need single, double or triple stops.

Comment: Thanks for youreply mikes. Yeah right now the cable is just put through the wholes which looks super ugly, that's why I wanted to find a proper routing solution. It's either this or 3D printing I guess.